# Error in SQL Select Query SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

I am using Sql Server 2008.

I have a table in which I want to insert multiple rows for which my query is

```
insert into tbl select MAX(v.vehicle_id),3,v.category,150,v.rate 
from vehicle v where v.parent_id=3 and v.category_id=0
```

My select query is giving error

```
select MAX(v.vehicle_id),3,v.category,150,v.rate 
from vehicle v where v.parent_id=3 and v.category_id=0
```

The error is

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'vehicle.category' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: Have you try to use GROUP BY?

Answer (score 3):

```
declare
@vehical_id bigint;

select @vehical_id=MAX(v.vehicle_id)
from vehicle v where v.parent_id=3 and v.category_id=0

insert into tbl select @vehical_id,3,v.category,150,v.rate 
from vehicle v where v.parent_id=3 and v.category_id=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, `Error is you are trying to select column name with aggregate function then need to group by clause`

```
 select MAX(v.vehicle_id),3,v.category,150,v.rate 
 from vehicle v where v.parent_id=3 and v.category_id=0 group by v.category,v.rate
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an aggregate function such as `MAX()`, you have to apply a `GROUP BY` at the end of your query for all your other attributes you've selected.

Here's an example structure:

```
SELECT MAX(attr1), attr2, attr3
FROM table1
WHERE attr2 = 'value'
GROUP BY attr2, attr3;
```